# How to check for a value in a matrix?

Tags: python, loops

If I have a matrix such as:

```
0,2,4
-1,4,2
3,4,2
```

How can I loop through the matrix to check if the matrix contains the value `1`? Where ,in this case, the matrix does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say your matrix is a 2D list:

```
matrix = [[0,  2, 4],
          [-1, 4, 2],
          [3,  4, 2]]
```

then you simply need to iterate through it:

```
def contains_1(matrix):
    for row in matrix:
        for element in row:
            if element == 1:
                return true
    # if it gets through all of that without returning true
    return false
```

This is a very verbose way of doing it, though - here's a more pythonic way:

```
def contains_1(matrix):
    return any([1 in row for row in matrix])
```

There are three parts to this one-liner:

- `1 in row` is `True` if the iterable `row` contains the element `1`, and `False` otherwise
- `[1 in row for row in matrix]` executes the expression `1 in row` for every element `row` in the iterable `matrix`, and returns a list of the results
- `any()` takes an iterable, like that list, and returns `True` if any of its elements are truthy; otherwise, it returns `False`.

You could also easily expand this code to accommodate searching for *any* element, not just 1:

```
def contains_element(matrix, element):
    return any(element in row for row in matrix)
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list of lists, you can convert it to a `numpy array`:

```
arr = numpy.array([[0,2,4],
                  [-1,4,2], 
                  [3,4,2]])
```

Now you can check if at least one element equals 1:

```
contains_1 = numpy.any(arr==1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use itertools' chain() function to flatten the matrix and look for 1 in the 1D result.

```
from itertools import chain
hasOne = 1 in chain(*matrix)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
exist = elt in A[0] or elt in A[1] or elt in A[2]
print(exist)
```

**e.g:**

```
   >>> A = [[1, 4, 5, 12], 
        [-5, 8, 9, 0],
        [-6, 7, 11, 19]]
   >>> exist = 1 in A[0] or 1 in A[1] or 1 in A[2]
   >>> print(exist)
   >>> True
```